# How to enable-migration well without conflict other migration?

Tags: c#, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

I want to update-database, but i see i first need to enable-migration first to the target database column
When i use this command on my console

```
Enable-Migrations
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining'.
To enable migrations for 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models.ApplicationDbContext.
To enable migrations for 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaRegCourses', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaRegCourses.
To enable migrations for 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaRegistration', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaRegistration.
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaCourses
The context type 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaCourses' was not found in the assembly 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining'.
```

I only need eNtsaCourses one, how can i resolve this issue with command console?

Answer (score 0):

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eNtsaRegistrationTraining.DAL.eNtsaRegCourses -force
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.